# Having problems aligning my header content

Tags: html, css

I'm recreating an article I found on [The Economist](http://www.economist.com/news/middle-east-and-africa/21718822-fight-hyperinflation-south-sudan-decides-tax-aid-workers-famine-war-and) and I'm having trouble creating the header. Please keep in mind I'm doing this without recreating their code verbatim. I'm trying to create my own implementation.

```css
header {
  background-color: #364043;
}

.header__content {
  width: 70%;
  margin: auto;
}

.header__left-content {
  display: inline;
  width: 50%;
}

.header__nav ul {
  display: inline;
}

.header__nav li {
  line-height: 0px;
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: middle;
}

.header__logo {
  padding-right: 25px;
}

.header__nav-link {
  padding-right: 15px;
}
```

```html
<html>

<body>
  <header>
    <div class="header__content">
      <div class="header__left-content">
        <div class="header__nav">
          <ul>
            <li class="header__logo">
              <img src="http://jobs.printweek.com/getasset/2eef9541-354f-4fec-8ce2-87b008f0323d/">
            </li>
            <li class="header__nav-link">
              <a href="google.com">Topics</a></li>
            <li class="header__nav-link">
              <a href="google.com">Print Edition</a>
            </li>
            <li class="header__nav-link">
              <a href="google.com">More</a>
            </li>
          </ul>
        </div>
      </div>
      <!--         <div class="header__separator"></div> -->
      <div class="header__site-functions">
        <p>right</p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </header>
  <div class="container"></div>
</body>

</html>
```

I'm having trouble getting the paragraph element, and ultimately its container to sit to the right as shown in the article.

Thoughts on this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `display: flex; justify-content: space-between;` on the element that wraps the the left/right portions of the header to put those in a row separated by the available space left over. And you can use `align-items` to align that content vertically.

```css
header {
  background-color: #364043;
}

.header__content {
  width: 70%;
  margin: auto;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  align-items: center;
}

.header__left-content {
  display: inline;
  width: 50%;
}

.header__nav ul {
  display: inline;
}

.header__nav li {
  line-height: 0px;
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: middle;
}

.header__logo {
  padding-right: 25px;
}

.header__nav-link {
  padding-right: 15px;
}
```

```html
<header>
  <div class="header__content">
    <div class="header__left-content">
      <div class="header__nav">
        <ul>
          <li class="header__logo">
            <img src="http://jobs.printweek.com/getasset/2eef9541-354f-4fec-8ce2-87b008f0323d/">
          </li>
          <li class="header__nav-link">
            <a href="google.com">Topics</a></li>
          <li class="header__nav-link">
            <a href="google.com">Print Edition</a>
          </li>
          <li class="header__nav-link">
            <a href="google.com">More</a>
          </li>
        </ul>
      </div>
    </div>
    <!--         <div class="header__separator"></div> -->
    <div class="header__site-functions">
      <p>right</p>
    </div>
  </div>
</header>
<div class="container"></div>
```

Comment: Worked perfectly. Much appreciated! I'll do some research on my own as to why this worked, but I'd love to hear the thinking behind this in your terms if you have a second.

Comment: @ZachHarriott no problem. The blurb at the top of my answer is my thinking :) What clarification do you need?

Comment: None actually, sorry. I re-read it and got a totally different understanding after taking a minute. Don't mind me lol.

Comment: @ZachHarriott haha no worries. For what it's worth, this is the guide I followed to learn flexbox https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/

Answer (score 1):

This is happening due to your `class="header__site-functions"` is ablock element and is taking the 100% of the width, so it doesn't fit in a line. You can use a floating element to fix it:

```css
header {
  background-color: #364043;
}

.header__content {
  width: 70%;
  margin: auto;
}

.header__left-content {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 50%;
}

.header__nav ul {
  display: inline;
}

.header__nav li {
  line-height: 0px;
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: middle;
}

.header__logo {
  padding-right: 25px;
}

.header__nav-link {
  padding-right: 15px;
}
.header__site-functions{
    float:right;
}
```

```html
<html>

<body>
  <header>
    <div class="header__content">
      <div class="header__left-content">
        <div class="header__nav">
          <ul>
            <li class="header__logo">
              <img src="http://jobs.printweek.com/getasset/2eef9541-354f-4fec-8ce2-87b008f0323d/">
            </li>
            <li class="header__nav-link">
              <a href="google.com">Topics</a></li>
            <li class="header__nav-link">
              <a href="google.com">Print Edition</a>
            </li>
            <li class="header__nav-link">
              <a href="google.com">More</a>
            </li>
          </ul>
        </div>
      </div>
      <!--         <div class="header__separator"></div> -->
      <div class="header__site-functions">
        <p>right</p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </header>
  <div class="container"></div>
</body>

</html>
```